# how to remove a unidirectional many to many association with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a unidirectional many to many association between Badges and Request like so :

Badges:

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Device
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="badges")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Badges
{
    /**
     * Unidirectional - Many users have Many favorite comments (OWNING SIDE)
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Request", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $invite;

}
```

Nothing special on the Request entity since this is a simple unidirectional association

Adding an association is fine.

But when removing the association I am doing this :

```
    $em = $this->CI->doctrine->em;

    //Get badges for new notifs
    $badges = $user->getBadges();

    if( $badges )
    {
        $invites = $badges->getInvite();
        if ( $invites )
        {
            foreach ( $invites as $key => $invite )
            {
                $badges->removeInvite( $invite );
            }
        }

        $em->persist( $badges );
        $em->flush();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

But it doesn't work and bring this error message for each invite I'm trying to detach from Badge:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  Undefined index:
>   000000005ede1b52000000009e09e897
>
> Filename:
>   ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>
> Line Number: 2739
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  array_pop() expects parameter 1
>   to be array, null given
>
> Filename:
>   Persisters/ManyToManyPersister.php
>
> Line Number: 143

Now if I only remove one single request from Badge:

```
            $invites = $badges->getInvite();
            if ( $invites )
            {
                foreach ( $invites as $key => $invite )
                {
                    if( !empty( $invite ) ) {
                        $badges->removeInvite( $invite );
                        $em->persist( $invite );
                        $em->persist( $badges );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I get :

`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException' with message 'A new entity was found through the relationship 'Entity\Badges#invite' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Entity\Request@000000007c08aa8800000000c42081b4. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={&quot;persist&quot;}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Entity\Request#__toString()' to get a clue.' in /var/www/meetmyfriends-dev/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/ORMInvalidArgumentException.php:59`

Note that I have persisted Request as specified in this error message ( Entity\Badges#invite is a Entity\Request )

Why is this happening ?
What should I do to fix it ? I just want to detach invite from Badges to remove to association.

Thanks

EDIT:
This is the implementation of Badges#removeInvite Method & Badges#addInvite Method:

```
    /**
     * Add invite
     *
     * @param \Entity\Request $invite
     * @return Badges
     */
    public function addInvite(\Entity\Request $invite)
    {
        $this->invite[] = $invite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove invite
     *
     * @param \Entity\Request $invite
     */
    public function removeInvite(\Entity\Request $invite)
    {
        $this->invite->removeElement($invite);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your Badges#removeInvite method? Or is this automagically created by Doctrine?

Comment: Thank Roel, This has automatically been generated by doctrine 2 but let me bring that up

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Doctrine ORM v2.4.5. What version of Doctrine ORM are you using?

Comment: It's a few months old, I would be surprised that this issue is coming from an internal bug. It seems to be a basic functionnality. Maybe is it coming from the entities Request or Badges themselves ? I would be happy to send you the code if you want to dig further. Many Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you try updating first, and see if that makes the problem go away.

Comment: No luck :/ I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ( $invites as $key => $invite )
            {
                if(!empty($invite)){
                    $badges->removeInvite( $invite );
                }
            }
```

Comment: Remove the cascade={"persist"} and check it once.

Comment: Thanks Nilesh but I added after several test when I red in the docs it was needed. It doesn't work wether or not Ihave the cascade persist.